# Not able to get access_token for Microsoft Graph API OAuth 2.0 using username & password

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get `access_token` using

`POST`  https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

endpoint using username and password where `tenant = {some tenant id}`

The parameters that I am using to make the request are:

```
client_id:{client_id}
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite
client_secret:{client_secret}
username:{username}
password:{password}
grant_type:password
```

I am getting the following error in response:

```
error: invalid_request
error_description : AADSTS90002: Tenant '' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription administrator.
```

I have the following permissions for my application available on Azure:
[image]

The documentation for this is available here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Comment: What are you using for a tenant id? The URI or the GUID?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Is tenant id equivalent to subscription id? Do I need to purchase a subscription for my application or the tenant id listed under my application would work?

Comment: I'm not sure which subscription you mean. Your tenant id is the unique ID of the AAD tenant you're authenticating against. I normally recommend using the URI for the tenant since it's easier to grok. The format is  `tenant-name.microsoftonline.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by purchasing a subscription and adding my user as an administrator.

After that, I added two permissions to my application to get the delegate access for using ROPC (Resource Owner Password Credential)authentication method and granted them with the administrator consent.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

On my side, it works. You should check your tenant whether your application is registered in this tenant.

[image]

Comment: My application is registered in the same tenant. Could you please tell me the steps to check that so that I can cross verify?

Comment: The user account whether has office 365 license. Because the calendar is used in the outlook, if your account is not an outlook user, it will also get this error.

Comment: I have access to calendar api.Do i need to subscribe for a specific service to register my application and get the tenant?